# Can we have bilingual help?

Tags: discussion, help-translated

Can [the help pages](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/) be modified? With assumptions that:

- Every help page will be either English, or English+Ukrainian; but, anyway, the English texts will remain **untouched**.
- Ukrainian text will go only **after** the English ones.
- We will prepare Ukrainian translations **ourselves**.
- We'll promise translations to be as close as possible.
- <sub>If the English text is going to be updated by SE administration — no problem, just drop the Ukrainian version (in order to not create any divergence; i.e. during the period after the update of the English text and before the fully updated Ukrainian translation is prepared, the Ukrainian translation just disappears).</sub>

It will simplify entrance for new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some parts of the **Help Center** and the **Site Tour** are available for edit by the moderators.

[What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259914/what-parts-of-the-help-center-can-site-moderators-edit)

I confirm that there are "edit" buttons in my interface.

Other parts are editable, too. Quoting the above source (emphasis mine):

> Note that Stack Exchange developers / Community Managers / employees can also **edit probably any other section of the site**, if you make a good enough case on your per-site meta.

I have not checked whether the other language sites bothered to translate the Help/Tour to their target languages.

I see no problem if we edit it for our convenience — especially this one:
"What topics can I ask about here?" (`http://foo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic`).

We should probably raise yet another Meta question asking about the proposed content — I'd prefer to have separate ones for each particular editable page and only after we agree here about the format first. [Here's how we do it](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/60) at Language Learning.SE.

I also agree it should contain both languages, **English first** and Ukrainian second to unify with other SE sites.

> If the English text is going to be updated by SE administration — no problem

Yes, it is no problem because we will have the "source code" in our Meta posts.

Comment: If you're looking for ideas on how to proceed with this, the [French Language site](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) implemented something similar.

Comment: @bluefeet, thank you very much! This layout looks precisely what we need.