# Якщо не Ukrainian.SE, то хто?

Tags: discussion, resources, community-wiki

У нас на сайті зʼявилося запитання, яке було закрите як off-topic:

[Зворотня асиміляція протягом 21 ст. Можлива?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5956/)

> Асиміляція російськомовними україномовних протягом минулого століття була блискавичною. За яких соціолінгвістичних умов може початися масова, помітна асиміляція російськомовних україномовними протягом поточного століття? Це взагалі реально?

Автор запитання написав наступний [коментар](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5956/#comment9539_5956):

> Шановні користувачі, підкажіть, будь ласка, де є в інтернеті подібні майданчики, де можна обговорювати такі теми. От цей сайт я знайшов випадково. — Oleksandr

Мені здається, що проблема очевидна:
*з одного боку*, є чітко визначений on-topic сайту Ukrainian Language.SE.
*з іншого боку*, є суспільний запит на соціокультурні теми, повʼязані з пригнічуванням української мови протягом періоду ворожої окупації, знищення або примусового змосковщення носіїв української мови та культури.

Отже, запитання: Які **альтернативні сайти** ми можемо запропонувати нашим користувачам для **обговорення суміжних тем**, які не підпадають під формальний on-topic сайту Ukrainian Language.SE, але можуть нести суспільний інтерес з точки зору відновлення української мови і подальшого її захисту від зазіхань?

Відповіді пропонується робити у вигляді списку посилань на такі сайти. Бажано робити невеличкий опис тематики і технології їхнього функціонування (як-то необхідності реєстрації тощо).

Comment: До речі, де саме чітко визначено on-topic сайту? Сторінка [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), схоже, просто placeholder, і нічого не прояснює (можна порівняти з такою ж сторінкою на [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Коли я голосувала за закриття тієї теми (про зворотню асиміляцію), я вибрала причину _primarily opinion-based_ - бо було неясно, чи справді соціокультурні теми про українську мову виходять за рамки сайту.

Comment: @kaamos Re:placeholder, насправді, багато сторінок Help/FAQ [доступні до редагування](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/8) модераторам. [Ось, як роблять](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) колеги. Інша справа, що ми усі не спромоглися це скласти докупи + перекласти… :-(

Comment: @kaamos, «де саме чітко визначено on-topic сайту» — наскільки я знаю, _чітко_ це не визначено поки ніде. На етапі definition заявки про створення цього сайту голосуванням було обрано [зразкові запитання](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001?phase=definition) — і, якщо я правильно розумію, саме вони в першу чергу мають визначати _scope_ цього сайту; але це дуже неконкретно. Розділ help ми (спільнота цього сайту, зокрема обрані спільнотою модератори) можемо редагувати самі, але ми за це не бралися (зокрема тому, що, по-моєму, було замало людей для ухвалення остаточного рішення).

Comment: @Sasha ось натрапила на [scope](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22564): questions _related to Ukrainian Language (its orthography, grammar, syntax, punctuation, phonetics, etc; sometimes — word etymology and history of language) — but not Ukrainian cuisine, sport, history, politics, etc._ Мабуть, можна трішки підправити це визначення, запропонувати на меті кінцевий варіант і, якщо особливо не буде заперечень, виставити на help. Бо кворуму для ухвалення остаточного рішення можна і не дочекатися)

Comment: @kaamos, ну, власне, то я писав :) (тобто його варто сприймати суто як пропозицію, а не як щось вагоме). А з формальної точки зору scope було окреслено саме зразковими запитаннями, наскільки я розумію. Але я лише «за», якщо Ви підправите те визначення, виставите на обговорення й ми занесемо його в help.

Comment: @Sasha я зрозуміла, що то ви писали) Мала на увазі, що натрапила на готовий, раніше вже написаний scope. Дописала його і [створила тему](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259) для обговорення.

Answer (score 3):

Часто чи подекуди тут бачив запитаня навколо проґрамистських тямок. Певен, декотрі з нас вже знають про наступного, але про всяк вже напишу.

Не можу порадити осїдок, але [одну тему](https://replace.org.ua/topic/1728/) з **Ріплейс**, де таке обговорюють чи можуть віподівсти.

---

Також, гадаю, же [загальнисько](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/) від **р2у** може дати змогу обговорити декотрі теми, котрі тут вважати ймуть ся позатемовими чи дуже безмежною.

Answer (score 2):

- [osv.org.ua](https://osv.org.ua/)
- [vseosvita.ua](https://vseosvita.ua/)
- [osnova.com.ua](http://osnova.com.ua/)
- [vsimosvita.com](https://vsimosvita.com/)
- [naurok.ua](https://naurok.ua/)

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-Ukrainian-language-websites