# What topics can I ask about here? – Our custom help page

Tags: discussion, scope, help-translated

Apparently, the scope of the Ukrainian Language Stack Exchange site is not yet clearly defined. Some guidance on the questions that are welcome here can be inferred from the [example questions](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001?phase=definition) suggested during the definition phase of the proposed Ukrainian.SE.

However, we cannot expect the newcomers to know about those example questions, let alone to study them before making their first post. There should be a simpler way to learn which questions are on-topic for this site.

I suggest we prepare a custom [“What topics can I ask about here?”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page within the Help Centre (moderators [should be able to edit it](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/can-we-have-bilingual-help)). Other language sites have made good use of this page, adapting it to their preferences. See help pages for [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Russian](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I’m adding a draft of the help page in a community wiki post below. Some parts of it are adapted from the corresponding pages of other language SE sites. Feel free to comment on it, edit it or suggest your own version as a separate answer.

I feel like the participants who have been on the site from its inception are much better equipped to prepare the help page discussed. I decided to start this topic only because someone needs to kick-start the process anyway.

Also, we can translate the help page final draft to Ukrainian when it’s ready.

Comment: it's a good idea, I'll be able to discuss it on Sunday.

Answer (score 6):

### *For English scroll down*

**Ukrainian Language** — це сайт запитань і відповідей для лінгвістів, учителів, студентів і будь-кого, кому просто цікаво уточнити той чи інший момент щодо **української мови**.

На цьому сайті ми вітаємо питання на такі теми:

- Граматика, орфографія і пунктуація;
- Вживання слів, вибір поміж словами і значення слів;
- Інші галузі лінгвістики (етимологія, фонетика, морфологія, синтаксис тощо);
- Переклад певного вислову або ідеї на українську зі спробою самостійного дослідження;
- Запити ресурсів, що стосуються української мови.

Ми не вітаємо:

- Питань про українську літературу, історію, політику абощо, якщо вони прямо не стосуються української мови.
- Питань про інші мови, окрім української (включно з питаннями про переклад з української на іншу мову).

Питання можна публікувати українською або англійською. Відповідаючи на питання, намагайтеся відповідати тою мовою, якою поставлене запитання.

На цьому сайті дуже схвалюється спроба показати власне дослідження питання. Якщо на ваше питання можна відповісти, подивившись у словник або інше загальновідоме джерело — спробуйте це зробити. Якщо це не допомогло, поясніть у питанні, чому вам недостатньо цих джерел для відповіді.

Тут ви можете ознайомитися з детальнішою інформацією: [Хороші питання і хороші відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/).

Також перегляньте: [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Перш ніж опублікувати своє запитання, [перевірте](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search), чи хтось не поставив схоже питання раніше.

---

**Ukrainian Language** is a question-and-answer site for linguists, teachers, students and anyone interested in the finer points of the Ukrainian language.

We welcome questions on the following topics:

- Grammar, spelling and punctuation
- Usage, word choice and meaning
- Other branches of linguistics (etymology, phonetics, morphology, syntax etc.)
- Translation of a particular expression or concept to Ukrainian
- Resource requests that concern Ukrainian language

The questions that are out of scope for this site:

- Questions about Ukrainian literature, history, politics or anything that does not directly relate to the Ukrainian language
- Languages other than Ukrainian (including translations from Ukrainian to other languages)

You can post your questions in either Ukrainian or English. When answering the question, try to answer in the language of the question.

We encourage you to show your research in your query. If your question could be answered by a dictionary or another general reference, consult these. Explain why this did not help you when asking your question.

You can read more on [what questions and answers are considered good for this site](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/).

See also: [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Please [look around](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before.

Comment: Мені все подобається. Лиш пропоную зробити переклад на українську і поставити його або першим, як у іспанців, або другим, як у французів. Я почав перекладати. Зараз продовжую.

Comment: Мій переклад можна активно редаґувати. Одразу погоджую викидання згідно з правописом літер ґ.

Comment: @P.Vowk чудовий переклад! Я ще завтра його перечитаю і, може, внесу якісь невеликі зміни (щодо ґ чи ще щось).

Comment: Дякую. Я робив нашвидкуруч, то не вагайтеся, якщо десь бачите помилки, і виправляйте, я потім подивлюся, що ви змінили.

Comment: @P.Vowk гляньте, чи з новою редакцією все ок) Я ще думала змінити речення _"На цьому сайті дуже схвалюється спроба показати власне дослідження питання."_ щоб пересічний користувач міг легше зрозуміти, чого від нього очікують. Але якось нічого кращого на думку не спало)